# How does JOIN works when it sees two tables with duplicate entries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Say A and B.

Table A:

```
Id  value  
1   A  
2   B  
1   C
```

Table B:

```
Id  value  
2   AA  
2   BB  
4   CC
```

Now I write a simple left join

```
select A.Id
      ,A.Value
      ,B.Id
      ,B.Value
from A   
  left join B   
    on A.Id = b.Id
```

This shows me multiple entries. Why so?

Comment: In your example, your join condition matches one row in table A with two rows in table B. Therefore the resultant set contains 2 rows.

Comment: Why not? You only asked for rows where the two `Id`s match; you didn't tell it that you want 'duplicates' filtered out, or how. I say 'duplicates' because `2 AA` and `2 BB` are obviously _not_ duplicates, as they're different. But an `inner join` without qualification wouldn't filter out actual duplicates, either, again because you didn't tell the DBMS to do so.

Comment: You need to be more clear: You get multiple entries because you have multiple records in each table. This is not what you mean, I'm sure. Please explain your expectation, and your motivation for that expectation

Comment: I should also note that you say you are performing a left join, then show an example using an inner join. They are *different things*.

Answer (score 0):

When you `left join` two tables together in SQL, you are asking the database to look at all the values in the first table's specified column and find *any and all* that match in the specified column of your second table.

This means that if the database finds two rows of data with `ID = 2` as per your example, it will bring both back.